# How can i get the name of the Foreign Key on Django List View with qyery returns None

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-generic-views

I want to display on the page the name of `categoria`

When there is at least one series, I can get the name.  Otherwise, it just returns none!  I am trying to create a new context variable to pass the **categoria name**.  But I fell I am doing something wrong... and complicated also...

Can someone help me to pass the `categoria` name into template even if there is no series returned?

Thanks...

#### Error Displayed

```
DoesNotExist at /categoria/15
Categoria matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/categoria/15
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Categoria matching query does not exist.
```

#### view.py

```py
class CatergoriasSeriesView(ListView):
    model = Serie
    template_name = 'categorias_series_of.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Serie.objects.filter(categoria=self.kwargs['categoria'])
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cat'] = self.kwargs['categoria']
        context['cat_name'] = Categoria.objects.get(categoria=self.kwargs['categoria'])
        return context
```

#### models.py

```py
class Categoria(models.Model):
    categoria = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="Nome da categoria", help_text="colocar aqui o texto de ajuda")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categorias"
        verbose_name = "categoria"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('series_da_categoria', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Serie(models.Model):
    serie = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="Série", help_text="colocar aqui o texto de ajuda")
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(
        Categoria, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

#### HTML template

```html
{% if object_list %}
  {% for serie in object_list %}
    <div>
      {% if forloop.first %}
      <h1 class="main-header">Categoria: {{ serie.categoria }}</h1>
      (...)
        {% if object_list|length == 0 %}
            Não foi encontrada nenhuma série
        {% elif  object_list|length == 1 %}
            Foi encontrada <span class="destaque">apenas uma</span> série
        {% else %}
        We have found <span class="destaque">{{ object_list|length }} séries</span>
        {% endif %} in category <span class="destaque">{{ serie.categoria }}</span>. </h5>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <div>
    <h1 class="main-header">Categoria: {{ cat_name }}</h1>
    (...)
    <h5>No series Yet</h5>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['cat'] = self.kwargs['categoria']
    context['cat_name'] = Categoria.objects.filter(categoria=self.kwargs['categoria'])
    return context
```

Template

```
    <h1 class="main-header">Categoria: {% for name in cat_name %} {{ name }} {% endfor %}</h1>
```

Comment: I have tried these changes, unfortunately, do not render for me...

Comment: it shuld be render

Comment: what do you  get from self.kwargs['categoria']